# Convert " to ' inside html

Tags: php, html

The code I've tried:

```
$var = '<a href="hellow"> Test </a>'; // Convert " to '

echo preg_replace('/<([^<>]+)>/e', '"<" . str_replace(\'"\', "\'", "$1") . ">"', $var);
```

Comment: I'm curious, why would you want to do this?  It might be best to use a DOM parser to load the whole document, then output your document with single quotes instead of double.

Comment: That's not recommendable @Brad the document could have nested quotes marks.

Comment: Using JSON to pass javascript functions. Among php, ajax and JSON.

No bug json html and javascript function, passing quotes "between them.

Comment: Just a note: `PREG_REPLACE_EVAL` has been [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Comment: is there a possibility of `"` flying arround elsewhere? If not just do `str_replace('"','´\'', $var)`

Comment: No, you have to use regular expression only to convert double quotes in single quotes, just inside the html

Comment: Not working, possible exemple: $var = ' kkk"s <a f="page.php"> Test </a>'; // Convert " for ' echo preg_replace('/<*("*)*>.*<\/*>/U', "'", $var);

Answer (score 0):

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/<([^<>]+)>/',
    function($m) { return str_replace('"', "'", $m[0]); },
    $var);
```

Comment: Don't just say "not working". Explain what's not working for you.

Comment: OOOOOO thank you, I love you, thanks a lot brother worked now!