# add bar invested in double quotes with javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var = invert ('HTMLBody ("Love"s ");');
```

staying equal to:

using `invert` to stay more or less the same, with `\`, only within the `HTMLBody`:

```
var = invert ('HTMLBody ("Love\"s ");');
```

I want to put `\` var inside, and can not be in quotes function `HTMLBody` put `\` only what you have inside the function `HTMLBody` in `var`

What is the function `invert`? Using regex?

Comment: say wha? edit your comment.. try english

Comment: I want to put \ var inside, and can not be in quotes function HTMLBody put \ only what you have inside the function HTMLBody in var

Comment: Are you trying to swap quotes in the code statement or the value/contents of the `String`?

Comment: Eyes! Just inside HTMLBody(), Using: invert ('HTMLBody ("Love"s ");'); HTMLBody within () reverse "to \"

Comment: are you saying you want to replace only the double quote within `Love"s` to `Love\"s` but not the double quotes enclosing this string?

Comment: @GuilhermeS.Mendes There likely isn't guaranteed way to accomplish what you want, which seems to be finding the best way to fix a invalid `String` of code automatically. If the `String` is a literal, as it is here, just edit it. If it's generated, maybe describe how it was generated. Based on [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17915374/): if it was `echo`'d from PHP, try [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) to get a properly-formatted JavaScript `String`.

Comment: EYES! @Harry... invert ('HTMLBody ("Love"s ");').replace(/"/g, '\"'); Not working, alert js: HTMLBody(\"Love\"s\"); ... here: HTMLBody("Love\"s")

Comment: I am using json_encode. He returns in JSON: "fz_alert", "alert (" Hellow "s hehe"); "But when: eval (data.fz_alert); .. From error because no ta ta putting \ in double quotes inside the function passed via JSON, and I want an expression that puts \ in double quotes only within ("here" s ") = (" here \ 's ");

Answer (score 0):

Since you've stated that the snippet is at least partially generated from PHP, you'd honestly be better served fixing that code so the snippet is generated properly rather than trying to fix the result after-the-fact.

[Edit] For example, if you started with:

```php
$functionName = 'HTMLBody';
$arguments = array('Love"s ');
```

You can [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) each `$argument` with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map):

```php
$encodedArgs = array_map('json_encode', $arguments);
```

Then, combine the `$functionName` and `$encodedArgs`, and once again encode as JSON to produce a `String` literal of the code:

```php
echo json_encode( $functionName . '( ' . implode(', ', $encodedArgs) . ' )' );
```

This should `echo` the following ([demo](http://codepad.org/riIqi9Tx)):

```
"HTMLBody( \"Love\\\"s \" );"
```

For the example in your comment, the starting values would be:

```php
$functionName = 'functionjsalert';
$arguments = array('type"s" here', 'value"s here');
```

Which should result in ([demo](http://codepad.org/PEOprzut)):

```
"functionjsalert( \"type\\\"s\\\" here\", \"value\\\"s here\" )"
```

---

---

---

To accomplish this with Regular Expressions, the string should be somewhat *regular*.

So, if it always follows the format of a `function` call with a single `String` argument, albeit with too many unescaped quotations:

> *functionName* (" *stringValue* ");

Note: If the `String` of code includes multiple arguments, then this isn't possible. There's no reliable way to recognize when a `"` is part of a value or is supposed to delimit one.

But, the following should work:

```
function invert(snippet) {
    return snippet.replace(/(\w+\s*\(\s*\")(.*?)(\"\s*\)\s*;)/, function (_, pre, sub, post) {
        return pre + sub.replace(/(")/g, '\\$1') + post;
    });
}

var result = invert('HTMLBody ("Love"s ");');

console.log(result); // HTMLBody ("Love\"s ")
```

The 1st RegExp matches 3 individual parts:

- `(\w+\s*\(\s*\")` matches the function name, left parenthesis, and 1st double-quote

  `pre === 'HTMLBody ("'`
- `(.*?)` matches anything in between the previous group and the next

  `sub === 'Love"s '`
- `(\"\s*\)\s*;)` matches the last double-quote, the right parenthesis, and the semicolon

  `post === '");'`

The 2nd RegExp then simply searches the middle group, `sub`, for any `"` and places a `\` before them.

And, if `invert` already exists and serves another purpose, rename this function as desired.

Comment: Ops: var myfunction = 'num_jsfunction("div", "text love"s hum")'; eval(myfunction);.. Error = num_jsfunction("div\", \"text love\"s hum")'; // Error in \ where it should not!

Comment: @GuilhermeS.Mendes As I mentioned, with more than 1 argument, this isn't possible. Beyond the first and last, every other `"` looks the same. So, there's no way to reliably determine whether they should delimit the string or be escaped as part of it. And, commas aren't enough of a guide -- `",",",",","` could be anywhere from 1 to 3 arguments.

Comment: will? var logjs = 'functionjsalert("type"s" here", "value"s here");'; eval(convert(logjs)); // eval = functionjsalert("type\"s" here", "value\"s here");

Comment: @GuilhermeS.Mendes Again, it's not going to be easily done after-the-fact. But, I've updated the 1st part of my answer to demonstrate how you could accomplish the output needed from PHP.

Comment: My brother, explication: www.varn.tk/17